# What is JSF unit?

Tags: jsf

I am doing work on JSF unit so can anyone give me the simple example of JSF unit also some useful link which is good for beginner..

Comment: the reference documentation wasn't enough?

Comment: @Bozho i am beginner of JSF unit? so i need some simple example of JSF unit.

Comment: Why the question mark? And I asked you whether the reference documentation of JSF unit wasn't helpful. http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JSFUnitDocumentation

Comment: sry for question mark. yes on google lot of result's are there but i thought that some one knows extra and useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

> JSFUnit is a test framework for JSF
>   applications. It is designed to allow
>   complete integration testing and unit
>   testing of JSF applications using a
>   simplified API. JSFUnit tests run
>   inside the container, which provides
>   the developer full access to managed
>   beans, the FacesContext, EL
>   Expressions, and the internal JSF
>   component tree. At the same time, you
>   also have access to parsed HTML output
>   of each client request.

Reference: [first google result](http://www.jboss.org/jsfunit).

---

**EDIT**

And a [hello world](http://labs.jboss.com/jsfunit/gettingstarted.html).